# browser extension: dynamically disable content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a browser extension with a content script that runs on all urls.

```js
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "permissions": [],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would now like to allow the user the *disable* the content script on certain sites, e.g., by having her click on a button in the popup. How would I go about this?

Comment: Don't declare it at all. Use browser.contentScripts API in the background script so you can re-register it when requested with the new exceptions.

Comment: Ah, in chrome extensions it'll be chrome.declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript action (it works in stable despite what the documentation implies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the background script (with `"activeTab"` and `"https://*/"` permissions), one can inject any script using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  const inject = /.*:\/\/.*stackoverflow.com\/.*/.test(request.url);

  if (inject) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'foobar.js'
    });
  }

  // Send an empty response to avoid warning
  sendResponse({});
});
```